# Can you come up with such verb?

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology

> He wounded himself.
>
> He pinched himself.
>
> He stabbed himself.
>
> He looked at himself.

In all these cases the action proceeds from the agent (which is also a subject) and is directed at this very agent. Let's call this phenomenon an "short-circuit action" (I am sure there should be a correct grammatical term for this). In all these cases the short-circuit actions are expressed by using '-self'.

I wonder if there are such verbs in English that would also express short-circuit action, but '-self' would not be needed then? I know there are such cases in other languages.

Can you come up with such verb?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The term you are looking for here is not "short-circuit" but *reflexive*.

> REFLEXIVE:  Grammar denoting a pronoun
> that refers back to the subject of the
> clause in which it is used, e.g.,
> "myself"

You could substitute "self-" and "auto-" as prefixes for some verbs to get rid of the reflexive pronoun:

> Rob was largely self-taught.
>
> If you don't stop drinking you are going to auto-destruct.

Comment: Thanks for "auto-destruct" - that's something of the kind that I was looking for. By the way, I wasn't looking for any grammatical terms in my question.

Comment: @brilliant: I know you weren't, but as it can't hurt to know the proper name for the concept you were trying to express I thought I would throw that in for free.

Comment: @Robusto: Are there any hard and fast rules as to when you should use auto vs self? Rob was a self-harmer sounds more correct to me than Rob was an auto-harmer. Does it depend on the verb?

Comment: @Andy F: I don't think there are any rules, but I usually hear "auto-" used with words derived from Latin, and "self-" used with words derived from Anglo-Saxon. But I would not want to fall on my sword defending that rule.

Comment: @Robusto: Well, thanks for throwing this term for free, but I already knew that term, except couldn't recall it right away while asking this question. Your words "I know you weren't" seem to contradict to your previous words "The term you are looking for here is..."

Comment: @brilliant: Well, sorry for enlightening you then. No good deed goes unpunished, it seems. Also, I believe I may as well stop responding to your questions entirely, since you seem not to appreciate information, and since you ask so many questions while accepting so few answers.

Comment: @Robusto, don't take offense, I didn't mean to offend you. Even if you throw a term here, which I already know, you still do a big favor to those who will come here later and happen not to know this term.

Comment: @brilliant: My final word on this: You said, and I quote, "I am sure there should be a correct grammatical term for this." That led me to believe that you did *not* know the term and that you were desiring to be enlightened. Either words mean something or they don't. Yours gave the impression that you did not know the term. If you do know a term and can't think of it, then say that. Either way I'd still try to help you out. Or would have.

Comment: @Robusto: I think we are dealing here with some cultural-linguistic differences. It is quite obvious to me now that saying in English something like "I am sure there should be a correct word for that" is an indirect request for helping out (like "Would you mind opening the window?"), whereas in my language it would be just a statement without any request implied. I didn't know about that and therefore offended you by wrong usage of English. Please receive my apologies. It's not the first time I run into this with native English speakers. I still have a long way to go learning English.

Comment: @brilliant: Apology accepted, and no hard feelings.

Answer (score 2):

(BrE) Not sure if it answers your question, but we use the verb *get* in some of these situations:

*get dressed, get washed, get ready, get lost* (in the nicest possible of ways)

I live in Poland, and Polish uses reflexive verb for a lot of these functions, but we don't have that luxury.

Incidentally *he suicided* sounds really weird to me, and my (US) spell check doesn't like it either.

Comment: I agree it **sounds** odd, but it's not wrong :-)

Comment: @ John Satta - Hi John, no question that it's in Merriam-Webster and it's apparently also in the OED. But it's not, for example, in Chambers Online, nor in any of the main dictionaries we use with advanced learners, so I think we have to accept its use is fairly limited. I'm also wondering if there's an AmE / BrE element here. I've never heard or seen it used in the wild. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Here is one example:

> He suicided last night.

Quoting [Merriam Webster online](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/suicided)

> suicide
>   verb
>   sui·cid·ed - sui·cid·ing
>   Definition of SUICIDE
>   intransitive verb
>   : to commit suicide
>   **transitive verb
>
>   : to put (oneself) to death**

Comment: This is correct, but it's worth noting (for non-native speakers) that it would be more normal to say "He committed suicide" rather than "he suicided". Either would be a good answer to the original question (though the longer one is strictly a verb phrase rather than a verb :-)

Comment: @psmears - I agree, in fact even most native speakers would probably say "committed suicide", but some members of some professions use it frequently (police, medical examiners)

Comment: In fact, of the over 15000 incidences of *suicide* in COCA, not one was used as a verb. A usage so rare as to be verging on the ungrammatical.

Comment: @nohat - sorry, what is COCA please?

Comment: @John the Corpus of Contemporary American English: http://www.americancorpus.org

Comment: I’ve never come across this use of _suicide_ as a verb before, but I have heard people object to the phrase ***commit*** _suicide_ in jurisdictions in which suicide is not a crime.

Answer (score 1):

There are several verb where the self is implied if no other person is specified, as in:

> He dressed.

Comment: Also, "He washed"

Comment: These sounds very awkward to me without the "himself".